# How do I pass the current view name into my Google Analytics element?

Tags: cakephp, google-analytics

I am setting up GA within a Cake multi-page ordering process. One requirement is, that the "_trackPageview" push should include a variable representing custom URL paths, depending on the current step of the process (i.e. `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/dsl/shop/availability/$url_addendum']);`.

I did set up the GA JS snippet as a Cake element google_analytics.ctp:

```
<?php
$gaCode = Configure::read('xxx.ga.tracking_code');

if (!isset($url_addendum))
    $url_addendum = '';

if ($gaCode) {
$googleAnalytics = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '$gaCode']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/xxx/shop/availability/$url_addendum']);
  _gaq.push(['_gat._anonymizeIp']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxx']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
EOD;
echo $googleAnalytics;
}
?>
```

The order process is displayed utilizing a layout shop.ctp in which I added `echo $this->element('google_analytics');` into the header section. This is working fine of course.

My problem now is, that I'd need to trigger _trackPageView with my custom $url_addendum parameter, seperately per view/step of the order process. But without producing duplicates of the page view and without calling the whole GA-element within the body of each view.

So I guess the question is: Is there a way to leave the GA-element call in the head of the layout (where it should be naturally, imho) and call custom _trackPageviews without having to use _trackEvent instead ?

Is there a way to pass the view name up to the layout in order to evoke a fitting call in the form of
`echo $this->element('google_analytics', array('url_addendum' => 'currentview'));` ?

Answer (score 1):

From the CakePHP perspective, you can access the following in your view template:

*Controller (e.g. PostsController)*

```
echo $this->request->params['controller'];
```

*Action (e.g. index)*

```
echo $this->request->params['action'];
```

*View (e.g. index - views by default have the same name as the corresponding action)*

```
echo $this->view;
```

*URL (e.g. Posts/add)*

```
echo $this->request->url;
```

You can select which of these are appropriate for your usage, but I see no reason why you can't echo one or more of these values straight into your JavaScript snippet.

I hope this helps!